# Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am sure this used to work.

`SELECT first_name, surname, id, time, MIN(timeinmilliseconds) FROM users WHERE team= '$key`'

I don't know where or why I would use a GroupBy Clause.

Comment: Define "used to work".  Running and producing an indeterminate result (as this code is documented to do in MySQL) is does not constitute correct code, in my opinion (unless that is explicitly the intention of the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SQL92 and earlier does not permit queries for which the select list,
>   HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that
>   are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally
>   dependent on (uniquely determined by) GROUP BY columns. For example,
>   this query is illegal in standard SQL92 because the nonaggregated name
>   column in the select list does not appear in the GROUP BY:

```
SELECT o.custid, c.name, MAX(o.payment)
FROM orders AS o, customers AS c
WHERE o.custid = c.custid
GROUP BY o.custid;
```

> For the query to
>   be legal in SQL92, the name column must be omitted from the select
>   list or named in the GROUP BY clause.
>
> SQL99 and later permits such nonaggregates per optional feature T301
>   if they are functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns: If such a
>   relationship exists between name and custid, the query is legal. This
>   would be the case, for example, were custid a primary key of
>   customers.
>
> MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If
>   the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default),
>   MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or
>   ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in
>   the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them. (Before
>   5.7.5, MySQL does not detect functional dependency and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled by default. For a description of
>   pre-5.7.5 behavior, see the MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual.)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

When there's no `group by` there are no columns for a functional dependence. You probably want a subquery to grab the value of `min(timeinmilliseconds)`.

Answer (score 1):

The functions MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),SUM(),AVG() are aggregate functions used in sql for grouping the result set.
As per the syntax, you need to mention the columns in the group by clause against which you are applying the aggregate function.

In your query you are using the MIN() function to find out the minimum time in milliseconds against the selected columns. So it should follow a syntax like below.

```
        SELECT first_name, surname, id, time, MIN(timeinmilliseconds) 
        FROM users 
        WHERE team= '$key'
        GROUP BY first_name,surname,id,time
```

Hope this will clear your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

It never worked

```
SELECT first_name, surname, id, time, MIN(timeinmilliseconds) 
FROM users 
WHERE team = '$key'
GROUP BY id, first_name, surname, time
```

I don't know that it will produce what you want, but it should run