# Get all the row using where min/max laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get **all** the row where I have the minimum value in 'temperature' but using min() or max() returning only the minimum or maximum values

At the moment I've to find before the minimum and than the 'acktime' I would like to get all the row in one time, but:

```
$tmp = rawData::whereDate('acktime','=', $thisDay)->min('temperature');
```

In this way I get only the minimum value

```
$tmp = rawData::whereDate('acktime','=', $thisDay)->get()->min('temperature');
```

In this way I get only the minimum value

```
 $tmp = rawData::whereDate('acktime','=', $thisDay)->get('acktime')->min('temperature');
```

In this way I get null

```
$tmp = rawData::with('acktime','temperature')->whereDate('acktime','=', $thisDay)->min('temperature')->get();
```

In this way I get error Call to a member function get() on float

Comment: I don't think there is a better way than using 2 loops: 1 to find the `min` value and 1 to find all records that contain the `min` value

Comment: It's kinda against each other both wanting min value and the row at the same time, as the min value is an aggregation of all the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$tmp = rawData::whereDate('acktime','=', $thisDay)->orderBy('temperature', 'asc')->first();
```

Comment: mmmh...your are a genius!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own select statement. `Using DB::raw` to do min operation. This will return one row, with the expected min data and `acktime`.

```
$data = rawData::with('acktime','temperature')
    ->whereDate('acktime','=', $thisDay)
    ->select('acktime', DB::raw('min(temperature) as temperature'))
    ->first();
```

Comment: Yes, it's what I'm doing now but in differet way, I get this error with your code:

`Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: select `acktime`, min(temperature) as temperature from `raw_data` where date(`acktime`) = 2021-11-01 limit 1)
`
You kow why?

Comment: @StefanoMartini https://stackoverflow.com/a/39311286/14807111

Comment: As the error states you have to do a group by for this to work.  as stated in my comment on the question what you are trying to do is against each other. Can you group the data by acktime? or similar your query will have multiple rows, which column can it be grouped by?